# External magnetic field strength of toroidal coil at a distance from the center

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

The below diagram shows the magnetic field strength of a current-carrying wire wrapped around a torus:
[image]

At a given distance from the centre of the torus, how could we calculate the strength of the magnetic field ? Similar to a solenoid, this is worked on the z-axis (integrating biot-savart law for a current loop): e.g. :

$$B_{z}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\frac{2\pi R^{2}I}{(z^{2}+R^{2})^{3/2}}$$.

Would there be a similar approach towards the toroid shaped electromagnet?

Comment: What you have here is not a toroidal coil in the accepted meaning of the term. A toroidal coil is what you'd get if you could bend a long solenoid  into the shape of a hoop so that its ends touched each other. In practice you'd start with a hoop-shaped former and wind the wire helically around it, covering the whole of the hoop, and possibly adding more layers.

Answer (score 0):

As a first approximation for the field outside you can treat the toroid as a single loop of current (as in the sketch).  Look up the field of a magnetic dipole.  Other than that, you can calculate the field at points of interest by numeric integration.

Comment: If we treat the toroid as a single loop of current, sure we could just use the formula I posted above in the question ? Moreover, how does the field of a magnetic dipole relate to this ?

Comment: A single loop of current is a magnetic dipole.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula you have above and take the sum of the field from both solenoids e.g. the centre of the torus has equal distance and therefore has double the amount than with just 1 solenoid same distance.